# wkhtmltopdf in Debian

Tags: firebase, debian, wkhtmltoimage

I'm trying to get wkhtmltoimage to work in a 64-bit Debian based environment.

I'm using [node-wkhtmltoimage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltoimage) in a node project. I dev on a mac, and using the mac binary from wkhtmltopdf, I get it to work fine. Then when I use the linux binary (tried both the linux binary and the linux(Debian) binary from the [wkhtmltopdf downloads page](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)), it does not convert my html to image at all.

I am deploying this into a firebase environment, which is the Debian 64-bit environment. Anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: I'm having an issue with wkhtmltoimage too when running on debian, it takes too much time. Could you please the steps that you followed for installing it and using it ? Thank you

Comment: @Ghita I never got my issue solved here, so I abandoned and moved on to a different solution. Firebase wouldn't allow the install I needed. The environment I moved to was not Debian, so I have no answers unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply